# How will pandas override the default delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Test data are as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
     ipl_data = {'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings',
                     'kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 
            'Royals', 'Riders'],
            'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2],
            'Year': [2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2016, 
             2014, 2015, 2017],
            'Points': [876, 789, 863, 673, 741, 812, 756, 788, 694, 701, 
             804, 690]}
  df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)
```

The original format of pandas is as follows:

```
     Rank       Year     Points
0  -15.000000 -11.618950  12.843272
1    5.000000  -3.872983   3.020286
2   -7.071068  -7.071068   7.071068
3    7.071068   7.071068  -7.071068
4   11.547005 -10.910895  -8.608621
```

But I hope to achieve the following results:

```
  Rank       Year     Points
  @-15.000000;-11.618950;12.843272~@5.000000;-3.872983;3.020286~@-7.071068;-7.071068;7.071068~
```

Explanation: @ symbol represents the beginning of a row of data, ~ symbol  represents the end of a row of data,; symbol is the separator

What should I do, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ipl_data = {'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings',
                     'kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 
            'Royals', 'Riders'],
            'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2],
            'Year': [2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2016, 
             2014, 2015, 2017],
            'Points': [876, 789, 863, 673, 741, 812, 756, 788, 694, 701, 
             804, 690]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)

def f(row):
    return '@'+';'.join(row.astype('str').tolist())+'~'

''.join(df.apply(f, axis=1).tolist())
```

Output:

```
'@Riders;2;2017;690~@Riders;2;2017;690~@Riders;2;2017;690~@Riders;2;2017;690~@Riders;2;2017;690~@Riders;2;2017;690~@Riders;2;2017;690~@Riders;2;2017;690~@Riders;2;2017;690~@Riders;2;2017;690~@Riders;2;2017;690~@Riders;2;2017;690~'
```